# Async and Request, return results

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, request

Having trouble working with request and async NPMs, new to JS as well.

```
    var queries = getURLS();

    async.map(queries, function(url, callback) {
        var options = {
            url: url,
            proxy: config.ProxuURL + ":" + config.ProxyPort,
            headers: {
                'SwitchProxy': location,
                'User-Agent': getUA()
            },
            resolveWithFullResponse: true
        };

        request(options, function (err, res, body){
            if (!err && res.statusCode === 200) {
                var urls = [];

                var $ = cheerio.load(body);

                $('h3.r a').each(function(i) {
                    urls[i] = getDomain($(this).attr('href'));
                });

                //How do I return urls so I can access it outside of the async loop?
            }
        });
    });
```

If I console.log(urls) I receive 10 arrays of domain names, I want to aggregate all of them into one master list so I can parse through it.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is actually add the callback function to your `async.map()` and look for the results there. Additionally, in order for your callback function to get the values you will need to return the callback with the data you want returned at the point which you want to return them.

```
var queries = getURLS();

async.map(queries, function(url, callback) {
    var options = {
        url: url,
        proxy: config.ProxuURL + ":" + config.ProxyPort,
        headers: {
            'SwitchProxy': location,
            'User-Agent': getUA()
        },
        resolveWithFullResponse: true
    };

    request(options, function (err, res, body){
        if (err)
            return callback(err, null);         
        if (!err && res.statusCode === 200) {
            var urls = [];

            var $ = cheerio.load(body);

            $('h3.r a').each(function(i) {
                urls[i] = getDomain($(this).attr('href'));
            });

            // return urls back to async.map()
            return callback(null, urls);
        }       
    });
}, function(err, results) {
    if (err) 
        console.log(err);
    else
        console.log(results) // Array of all URL Arrays returned from each queries iteration
});
```